# Concat list without duplicate

Tags: angularjs

I have two list, I concat them without duplicate value, I do this so I have duplicate value, why ..?

**In my HTML:**

```
..
          <list-of-items items="platforms.concat(platformsCible).unique()"
                           label="$item"
                           selected-item="platform"
                           createfunction="add_platform($name)"
                           selectable="true"
                           editable="false"
                           size="small">
            </list-of-items>
..
```

**In my JS**

```
propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page',  function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {
...
    $scope.platforms = [];

    /* Find all the platforms */
    PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.version).then(function(platforms){
        $scope.platforms = platforms;
    }).then(function(){
        /* If platform was mentionned in the route, try to find it or add it */
        if($scope.platform) $scope.add_platform($scope.platform);
    });

/* Find all the platforms cible */
if( $routeParams.versionCible != null) {
    PlatformService.get($routeParams.application, $routeParams.versionCible).then(function (platforms) {
        $scope.platformsCible = platforms;
    }).then(function () {
        /* If platform was mentionned in the route, try to find it or add it */
        if ($scope.platformCible) $scope.add_platform($scope.platformCible);
    });
}

    Array.prototype.unique = function() {
        var a = this.concat();
        for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
            for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
                if(a[i] === a[j])
                    a.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }

        return a;
    };

    }]);
```

Comment: Post example of `platforms`.

Comment: @dfsq i post example of platforms

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native angular tool: angular.extend(dst, src);
In your case it will be angular.extend(platforms, platformsCible)

It doesn't try to deep compare objects, only their key-value pairs, so it may work for you to get concated list of unique platforms.